# C chars and char* index to a pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to understand pointers.  when I declare

```
char* buffer = malloc(10);
```

`&buffer` is a `char**`  which makes sense and follows

```
char new_buf;
```

where `&new_buf` is a pointer or `char*`

What is `&buffer[5]`?

Apparently you can print it out with `%s`, so does that make it a string?

Comment: Once you get a handle on this, the head-scratcher will be the difference between `&buffer` and just `buffer`. Hint: its a type-thing.

Answer (score 3):

`buffer`'s type is `char *`, so `buffer[5]` which is equivalent to `*(buffer + 5)`, has a type of `char`. Therefore `&buffer[5]` 's type is `char *`.

Whether it's a string depends on if it's null terminated. For instance, if `buffer` points to a string `"hello,you"`, then `&buffer[5]` points 5 characters after `buffer`'s beginning, that's `",you"`, a string.

```
h e l l o , y o u \0
^         ^
|         |
buffer    &buffer[5]
```

Another more easy way to understand it is, `buffer` is equivalent to `&buffer[0]`, so `&buffer[5]` is the pointer that points 5 characters after it.

Answer (score 1):

`&buffer` is a `char**`

`&buffer[0]` is a `char*`

`&buffer[5]` is a `char*`

`&new_buf` is a `char*`

C doesn't really have strings, just arrays of characters. Most people equate a `char*` to a string and it works as long as they maintain the convention of ending the string with a 0 char.

Answer (score 0):

buffer is the address of the first entry of the 10 byte array. This is the same as &buffer[0].

&buffer[5] is address of the sixth element of the array, and is actually the same thing as (buffer+5)

You could call printf("%s",buffer); or printf("%s",&buffer[5]); which may do something sensible if the array contains suitable ASCII characters with a null terminating character.

Answer (score 0):

`buffer` and `&buffer[0]` both are same and pointes to the first character of the character array.
`buffer` means `(buffer+0)`
`buffer[5]` means `*(buffer+5)`.
`&buffer[5]` means `(buffer+5)`.